# How to change digital clock to display time in 12 hour instead of military time in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, time

hello I am working on a launcher that has a digital clock that currently displays time in military time i want it to display in 12 hour format how do i do this??

heres my code for the activity

```
    public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {


        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);
        sentBitmap.recycle();

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        return (bitmap);
    }


}
```

heres the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:alpha=".4"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lock_gradient" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:background="@drawable/home"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photoButton"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/photo" />

</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    android:text="@string/time_placeholder"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="80sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:shadowColor="#7F000000"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="3"
    android:text="@string/undefined_username"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="17sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="8 notifications"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I have tired googling the issue and no luck :(

Any help links or feedback would be amazing!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Converting a clock from a 24 hour to a 12 hour clock really only means diving by two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there can be an easier fix to this assuming you are using java util Calendar:

```
    hourOfDay = "" + calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR); // changed to Calendar.HOUR
    textView1Object.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
```

Next time try to post relevant code so that we can help you faster.